# HP Hard Drive ABC Slots

Tags: hard-drive, hp-proliant

Ok so I have a hard drive that went out and a replacement drive was ordered per the same part # from the bad drive. On these driver there are 3 slots with tabs on these drives labeled A B C.
The BAD Drive has a TAB over slot B, while the new drive same part Number has tabs over Slot A and C. The A slot prevents the drive from being inserted into the server. Drive INFO HP Part# 407525-004 Server is a HP DL 180 G6...
Does anyone have knowledge of these slots / tabs and why these drives are different?

[image]

Comment: Do you have photos?

Comment: Pic added @ewwhite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the tray. If you still have the bad drive, take it out of the tray and put the new drive in the same tray (assuming that the drive itself is bad and not the tray, of course).

Comment: Yeah, just ignore it.